# If $a_{1}=1$ and $b_{1}=2$ show that $b_{5}-a_{5}<1/2^{45}$. Need help interpreting solution.

Tags: inequality

If $a_{1}=1$ and $b_{1}=2$ show that $b_{5}-a_{5}<1/2^{45}$.

$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_{n}b_{n}}$  , and $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+b_{n})$.

I've managed to work out that $b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{8}(b_{n}-a_{n})^{2}$. It was the solution in the back of the book. I do not however understand how this relates to the inequality which is to be shown.

Comment: First, note that $b_n-a_n\ge 0$ for all $n$ (this is the AM-GM inequality). Now, since $b_1-a_1 = 1$, your work shows that $b_2-a_2 < 1/8(1)^2 = 1/8$. Since $b_2-a_2$ is nonnegative and $b_2-a_2<1/8$, your work shows that $b_3 - a_3 < 1/8(1/8)^2 = 1/8^3$. Can you continue?

Comment: @JoeyZou That was just what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: Those two means get closer together very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$
b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{8}(b_{n}-a_{n})^{2},\quad n\ge1,
$$ one gets, with $n=1,2,3,4$,
$$
\begin{align}
b_{5}-a_{5}&<\frac{1}{8}(b_{4}-a_{4})^{2}
\\\\&<\frac{1}{8^3}(b_{3}-a_{3})^{2}
\\\\&<\frac{1}{8^7}(b_{2}-a_{2})^{2}
\\\\&<\frac{1}{8^{15}}(b_{1}-a_{1})^{2}.
\end{align}
$$